# Azure Websites SSL - Price per certificate or per binding?

Tags: azure, ssl, web

I have a wildcard SSL certificate for *.mydomain.com

I have 20 subdomains that I would like to secure using Azure Websites.

Will I be charged £5.4981/month or £109/month (20 x £5.4981/month)

On the pricing page it says ' £5.4981/month (per certificate supported)'
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/websites/

But when you add a new binding in Azure for each subdomain it says this might affect your pricing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about certificate pricing, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wildcard certificate. You are only going to pay for the certificate and not for each individual sub domain that you want to use. The number of websites that you want to host is not going to affect the price that you will need to pay for the certificate.

Do note that creating web sites in azure does come with additional costs. They can be found [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/).